# Trigger required attribute for form fields based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

If radio one (#choice_one) is checked how to make input field one (#field_one) required and if radio two (#choice_two) is checked how to make input form two (#field_two) is required and remove required from input field_one using JS?

```
<input type="radio"  id="choice_one">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_one" name="item_name" value="">
 <input type="radio" id="choice_two">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_two" name="item_name" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click`event :

```
$("#choice_one").on("click",function(){
     var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
     $("#field_one").prop("required",checked);
});
//and same thing with #choice_two
```

Or using a same function :

```
$("#choice_one,#choice_two").on("click",function(){
     var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
     $(this).next().prop("required",checked);
});
```